# adding PX back to div height

Tags: jquery

I am writing some jquery that gets the height of 2 divs and sets another div to the combined height.

```
var height1 = $("#heightSelector2").height();
var height2 =$("#heightSelector3").height();
var maxHeight = height1 + height2;
console.log(maxHeight);
```

How do I now set $("#heighSelector1") = maxHeight ? 
I know I need to add px back in there also and i've seen some examples but nothing clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way to do it.

`$("#heightSelector1").css("height",maxHeight + "px");`

Answer (score 5):

```
$("#heightSeletor1").height(maxHeight + "px")
```

To be honest, I don't believe you need to add the `px` back, but if you do, simply use the `+` operator to append it.

Comment: You can use the example without the + px : $("#heightSeletor1").height(maxHeight); 

Also you can user $("#heightSeletor1").css("height", maxHeight + "px"); In this example you do need the + "px"

Comment: @CatalinDeaconescu Exactly right, I mentioned that in my post already though.

Comment: Sorry about that Evan, I didn't see the update before I posted

Answer (score 1):

You no need to add px

try this

```
  $("#heightSeletor1").height(maxHeight)
```

Example:`$(selector).height(30);`

[see here](http://api.jquery.com/height/)